# Generate mysql schema from object with sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am tring to create my database schema using sequelize. The thing is that i have all the information about the rows and cols for the table in an array of objects.
For example we have this array of objects

```
const phones = [
  {
    price: 300,
    model: 'REDMI 5',
    color: 'black',
    4G: 'yes',
    3G: 'yes',
    'type sim card': 'nano',
    'dual sim': 'yes',
    EAN: '8806088938523',
  },
  {
    price: 323,
    model: 'GALAXY J3 2017 J330 DS SILVER',
    color: 'white',
    4G: 'yes',
    3G: 'yes',
    'type sim card': 'nano',
    'dual sim': 'yes',
    EAN: '8806088938424',
  },
  {
    price: 399,
    model: 'DESIRE 628 DS TERRA WHITE',
    color: 'pink',
    4G: 'yes',
    3G: 'yes',
    'type sim card': 'nano',
    'dual sim': 'yes',
    EAN: '8806088938444',
  }
]
```

So is there a way using Sequelize to create my schema based of this array, where every object is a row and every key-value pair can be col-value in the schema?

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically create the model based on the array?

Comment: @WilliamFleming yes, i am scraping a website, and all the information is coming dynamically.

Comment: I am far from a db designer, but the phones array could represent a table and each object is a record (or row) in the table.  The properties of the objects are what you will use to define the Sequelize model.  You will need to create the model beforehand with sequelize and use that to create the records in the database. http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/models-definition/